# Angular leaflet - How to handle markercuster click?

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm using Angular leaflet and I would like to get all markers when I click on a cluster. I can't find any events or methods that could do it ?

I'm using [Angular leaflet directive](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/) for my project.

Any help would be good !

Thanks

Comment: Read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28906467/4560292

Answer (score 0):

I went trough javascript markercluster code and I changed the behaviour during clusterclick in order to trigger an event. 
I know this isn't the best way to do it, but I think a quick patch in the original library would be good, because there is simply no easy way to do it.

I trigger now a markerclusterclick event that I could catch in my controller and do whatever I want on my cluster.